# Is there a JSON schema for Serilog?

Tags: json, schema, serilog

We exclusively use appsettings.json (and environment specific versions) to configure Serilog. I'd love to have intellisense when configuring Serilog in those files.

Does anybody know if they have a schema or if someone has created one and shared it?

Comment: Here's someone's attempt at one https://gist.github.com/turchenkoalex/ff9dc8443c3002eccf8df58020f82339

Comment: Just filed request for one in official repo https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/327